# Combining dictionary list elements is length is greater than 2

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary with lists for values.  The length of the lists must not be greater than 2.  What I need to do is combine the list elements starting at the second element and join with the next element until the length of the list is equal to 2.  My attempt below works but it seems like this could be done easier and I am just not seeing it.

```
testDict = {'60075566': ['A', u'foo'], 
            '60074783': ['B', u'one', u'two', u'three', u'four', u'five'], 
            '60069249': ['C', u'test1', u'test2', u'test3'], 
            '60075936': ['D', u'bar'], '60073582': []}


for key in testDict:
    while len(testDict[key]) > 2:
        dataSave = testDict[key][0]         #####save first element of the dictionary value#######
        newList = testDict[key]             #####create new list of values to change#######
        newList.pop(0)                      #####pop the first element, previosuly saved#####
        newData = ','.join(newList )        #####Join remaining elements#####
        testDict[key] = [dataSave, newData] #####Replace old value with new value
```

The above produces the answer but I feel like it can be improved:

```
{'60069249': ['C', u'test1,test2,test3'], '60075566': ['A', u'foo'], '60075936': ['D', u'bar'], '60074783': ['B', u'one,two,three,four,five'], '60073582': []}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way in those problems is to use a comprehension (here a *dictionary* comprehension) to rebuild a new dictionary with a condition on the value length:

```
testDict = {'60075566': ['A', u'foo'],
            '60074783': ['B', u'one', u'two', u'three', u'four', u'five'],
            '60069249': ['C', u'test1', u'test2', u'test3'],
            '60075936': ['D', u'bar'], '60073582': []}

result = {k:(v if len(v)<=2 else [v[0],",".join(v[1:])]) for k,v in testDict.items()}

print(result)
```

prints:

```
{'60075936': ['D', 'bar'], '60073582': [], '60075566': ['A', 'foo'], 
 '60074783': ['B', 'one,two,three,four,five'], '60069249': ['C', 'test1,test2,test3']}
```

in `v if len(v)<=2 else [v[0],",".join(v[1:])]`, the list/value is untouched if the length is 2 or less, else it's rebuilt from the first element and a joined string of the rest of the elements.